# Conflicting python version in jupyter notebook(Conda)

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

I am trying to setup Jupyter notebook using Conda, but the python version being used by notebook is not the same as the Conda environment.

I used the following command to create the 'python_jupyter' environment.

```
conda create -n python_jupyter python=3.6.5 ipykernel
```

But in the notebook, when I check the python version I get different results depending on how I am checking it. If I check using bash command I get the expected version number 3.6.5, but from python code, I get 3.6.3(which I am guessing the default one came with default Conda installation).

[image]

When I go back to the 'base'(default) environment, the version conflict is resolved,

[image]

Why there is a python version conflict in the first image, and how do I resolve it?

### Edit

When I run 'conda info' on the command line with 'python_jupyter' environment active I see python version is being reported as 3.6.3. But if I run 'python -V' I see python version 3.6.5. Why this discrepancy? Also when I try to update python using 'conda update python' it doesn't prompt me for an update which means conda thinks I am on the latest python version 3.6.5.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was solved by running `conda install ipython jupyter` on my `python_jupyter` environment. Since I were able to run `jupyter notebook` command with the default installation, I was under the assumption that jupyter notebook installation was complete.

[image]

`conda info` reports the version of Python in the base environment, and `conda list` or `conda list -f python` or `python -V` reports the version of Python in the currently active environment, in this case python_jupyter. [Source](https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/d/msg/anaconda/AhA-rrLP_rU/gygw6_1DBAAJ)

Comment: Thanks @Quazi Irfan, you saved me a day. 

In addition for those using jupyter lab you may need to change the command ```conda install ipython jupyter ``` to ```conda install ipython jupyterlab ```

Comment: What's the difference between `jupyter` and `jupyterlab`?

Comment: Yes, strangely if you don't do that the problem will still persist.