# Python package version (bokeh) in Jupyter Notebook different from version in Terminal

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, virtualenv, jupyter

I installed Bokeh into a virtual environment using pip in the terminal. However, when launching a Jupyter notebook server from this virtual environment, and opening a notebook, the version of bokeh (0.12.9) appears different from the version I installed in the terminal (0.13.0).

From the Jupyter notebook server terminal:

```
pip3 install --upgrade bokeh
...
python3
Python 3.6.4 (default, Mar  9 2018, 23:15:03)
GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bokeh
>>> bokeh.__version__
'0.13.0'
```

From a new iPython notebook:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
import bokeh
print(bokeh.__version__)

>>> 3.6.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul 20 2017, 13:14:59) 
>>> [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)]
>>> '0.12.9'
```

I have checked that the notebook is also running Python 3 (though it is a different version, which seems suspicious...)

How do I upgrade the version of Bokeh that runs in the notebook? The most closely related questions that I can find on Stack Overflow ([old sklearn version in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41768292/old-sklearn-version-in-jupyter-notebook), [Conflicting python version in jupyter notebook(Conda)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675004/conflicting-python-version-in-jupyter-notebookconda)) do not seem to work, probably because they are specific to conda, which I do not have installed.

Comment: do you have a another python installed outside of your environment? If yes, type `unset PYTHONPATH` in the terminal, before you start your environment.

Comment: Yes, the fact that Jupyter wasn't getting the "correct" version of Python was the issue. It was connecting to a different kernel. I tried a few things, and ultimately the thing that fixed it was upgrading ipykernel. After that, the virtualenv kernel became visible to Jupyter. Next time, I'll just use conda :)