# Python version in Jupyter Notebook (myenv: 'conda') different terminal version and I want to update

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm having the same issue reported [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50675004/conflicting-python-version-in-jupyter-notebookconda)

But I want to update it from Python 3.7 to 3.8. I don't know how to do that!

If i check in Terminal:

[Python version in Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DrfC5.png)

But when I check in my Jupyter Notebook:

[Version of python in 'conda' env. (3.7.10)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezaKe.png)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
conda install -c anaconda python=3.8
conda update --all
conda create -n py38 python=3.8
```

now you have a new virtual environment with name `py38` with python 3.8, where you can install everything again. There is no way to update python version only in some environment.

After that you can activate this env, install jupyter, and run it.

Also, try to use anaconda navigator UI to activate environment and run jupyter.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll try that.